# Changing The MahApps Metro Theme

Tags: wpf, visual-c++, themes, mahapps.metro

I know that the MahApps metro theme comes with "themes" (colour sets), but I don't know how to change them from the default settings in my WPF application.

I have followed the beginners tutorial at [MahApps.Metro Documentation](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/) (including adding the resource libraries at the top of the page), but it makes no mention about changing the theme.

The component/Styles/Colours.xaml file has the comment "from the cosmopolitan theme pack", which may be a helpful clue to someone better versed in WPF design than me.

I'm talking about an app-wide theme change, not an individual control.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to change the default colour scheme, just change which colour resource file is loaded.

from Blue:

```
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
```

to Red:

```
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Red.xaml" />
```

You can also change programatically (once you've loaded every colour resource file) using ThemeManager.ChangeTheme().

Comment: Thanks! Also, I discovered the base theme (which determines most of the colour scheme, the file you mentioned just changes the accents/highlights) can be changed with /Accents/BaseLight.xml or BaseDark.xml.

Comment: Where are these files at? I've loaded MahApps from the package manager and I can see the .dll file, but I can't find these xaml files to edit.

Comment: I think they're just bundled inside the dll. The source is at: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/tree/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Accents

Comment: @Rich Please if I need to make subtle changes like this to the default MahApps styles, does it mean that I need to edit the corresponding MahApps' xaml file and then recompile the dll?

Comment: Uh, I would presume so. You could also use a custom style based on the MahApps style, e.g. <Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTabItem}" x:Key="MetroLightTabItem">

Comment: @Rich Can we add our own colour theme without having to recompile any dll? EDIT: nevermind, the answer is yes - I found the XAML files on GitHub and made my own resource dictionary and added that to the merged dictionaries.