# Change selected Text Color in textbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

How can I change the color of selected text in textbox I try in textbox style.

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush" Color="#FFD1D1D1"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I also try that but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible directly.But you you are using something like MahApps you can change it theme color, thats affects the highlight text. 
To learn how to change this color, already have a question with a good answer there:

[Changing The MahApps Metro Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917657/changing-the-mahapps-metro-theme)